# Submit process is taking long time for Web page

Tags: c#, ektron

I have a dot net web application. There is one page where we enter data & submit the form.We upload the attachment before submitting the form.The submit action is taking long time almost minute for files with attachment of 650KB. The code behind is C#. We use third party API(Ektron).Its a CMS tool.

Please let me know , in what all ways i can analyse the bottle neck for the issue.Please provide open source Tool & the browser addons.. other than Page speed & Yslow .

Answer (score 0):

Please check if the time taken is for the request to initiate or the response to comeback to your browser..
It is only then you can look for a solution..

Answer (score 0):

To answer the second half of your question. At the very least most modern browsers (FireFox, Chrome and Safari) have a developer console that will give you a breakdown of the times taken in each request state on a per request basis. My personal preference is FireFox with FireBug as I find the Network pane view easy to interpret.

Answer (score 0):

Redgate ANTS Performance Profiler is pretty much the bees knees for troubleshooting performance problems in ASP.net.